# AdvancedDatagrid DataTipFunction

Tags: flex4, advanceddatagrid

i have a grouped AdvancedDatagrid. It looks like...

dataProvider - GroupingCollection2 - Grouping - GroupingField - summaries - summaryRow - fields.
Sorry for the strage Codefragemt. I try everything to paste a litte bit mxml-Code. But i fail...

And a AdvancedDataGrid Column with a long long description. I want to show a DataTip. In the grouped headline, the DataTip shows [Object][Object]. In the expanded lines, the DataTip works fine.

I assume, what I need is a DataTipFunction to fix this. In this function, i will receive a object (AdvancedDataGridColumn). But how can i reference to the data of the highlighted line? And how can i find out, if this is a groupedLine or an expanded?

Thank you for reading it
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adobe Document, it says that the DataTipFunction will look like this:

```
  private function tipFunc(value:Object):String
  {
      if (value is AdvancedDataGridColumn)
          return "Column Name";

      // Use the 'name' property of the data provider element.
      return "Name: " + value["name"];
  }
```

show the object you received could be an AdvancedDataGridColumn when user's mouse is over the Column Header, and while moving the mouse over a row in datagrid, the function will receive an Object that is the data item in dataProvider.

when you use grouping, the value item you received will contain a sub-item called 'children', so you can depend on that to determind whether it's an expanded leaf node or grouped node.

so you function could be:

```
  private function tipFunc(value:Object):String
  {
      if (value is AdvancedDataGridColumn)
          // return dataTip you want to show for column header
          return "Column Name";
      if(value.hasOwnProperty('children'))
          // return dataTip for grouped column item
          return "Grouped Item";

      // return data value in this column
      return value["dataField name"];
  }
```